# Is there a way to visualize the tris of a scene?

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to visualize the tris of a scene ?

[image]

I want to visualize them in the viewport, because sometimes I want to turn the hidden edge of some quads.

Answer (score 1):

## Selecting All Triangles

You can use the [MeshLint](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint) add-on to select all the triangular faces in your mesh.

Another way is to select a triangular face, **Select Similar** <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > **Polygon Sides** and this will select all tris.

[image: Using "Select Similar" to select all triangles]

## Rotating Edges

If you have a mesh where the quads have been converted to tris you can "turn" or "rotate" the orientation of the edge within that triangulated quad.

For example, in the screen shot below there is a Suzanne mesh that has been converted to all tris using the Triangulate Modifier. In Edit Mode if we select an edge that bisects a quad we can then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and from the contextual menu choose **Rotate Edge CW** or **Rotate Edge CCW** depending on whether you want Clockwise or Counter-Clockwise rotation (for a triangulated quad it makes no difference which you choose, the result is the same).

[image: Rotating an edge that bisects a triangulated quad]

### Further details

This operation can also be accessed from the menu under Mesh > Edges. It can be performed in all three selection modes (Vertex / Edge / Face).

If you plan to do this operation many times repeatedly it would probably be best to assign a keyboard shortcut to it. While the contextual menu is open you can right click on the menu items and assign shortcuts.

An example utilizing the Mac's "Command" modifier key: [image: Adding a custom keyboard shortcut to the Rotate Edge operation]

Comment: All quads are really made up of two tris with a "hidden edge" connecting two adjacent verts.  "Turning" a hidden edge means flipping which two verts are connected by the hidden edge.

Comment: I mean exactly what PGmath is saying

Comment: @PGMath thanks for clarifying. I get exactly what is meant now, didn't realize there was a name for that (a hidden edge). As for "turning", isn't the whole point of a quad that which two verts are connected is calculated automatically as the mesh deforms? I mean, isn't is supposed to "turn" itself? Otherwise a quad would be no different from two tris connected by a common edge, right? Unless OP is talking about a mesh that has been converted to all tris, in which case I will now add something more to my answer (how to rotate or "turn" an edge).

Comment: @Mentalist  I don't believe hidden edges are calculated on the fly.  The (biggest) advantage of quads is edge flows.

Comment: @PGMath Hey... it seems you are right, they're not calculated on the fly. This is actually kind of shocking to me, as I had been under the impression that they were calculated automatically to achieve the most desirable deformations. Maybe hidden edge orientation doesn't make as big of a difference as I thought. If it looks alright in the end all is well. But that still doesn't fully answer OP's question about how to turn hidden edges. As far as I know there is only a way to turn "real" edges.

Answer (score 1):

The 'tris' count shown in the info header is only an approximated count of how many triangles the mesh will be converted to. The only way to see the triangular polys used is to triangulate the mesh. A non-destructive way is to use a triangulate modifier and enable wire display for the object.

[image]

[image]

I'm not certain that the modifier will match other triangulate steps but you can apply the modifier to ensure your final triangulated mesh matches.